# Repaint BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage, repaint

I'm trying to do a small image processing with Java. The user should be able to load an image and add some easy modifications to the image by clicking a button.
Loading and displaying the image is no problem but when I try to make a binary image out of it the repaint() method makes me a black image on the screen.
I think the problem is with the repaint()-method. I already used the search function and Google but I still have no idea what's wrong in my code.
That's what I have so far:

```
public class ImageProcessing extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private  JPanel imagePanel;
    private  JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JButton binaryButton;
    private  JButton loadButton;    
    private BufferedImage image;    
    private final String WINDOW_TITLE = "Image Processing";

    public ImageProcessing() {
        createWindow();
    }

    private void createWindow() {
        this.setTitle(WINDOW_TITLE);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        this.setSize(500, 500);

        imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        loadButton = new JButton("Load image");
        loadButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(loadButton);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        binaryButton = new JButton("binary");
        binaryButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(binaryButton);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource() == this.loadButton) {
           String filePath = getImageFile();
        if (filePath != null) {
          try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
           // imageBackup = image;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          this.repaint();
        }
       } else if (e.getSource() == this.binaryButton) {
           image = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
           imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
           this.repaint();
       }
    }

    private String getImageFile() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = null;
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
          return file.getPath();
        } else
          return null;
    }       

    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
       public void paint(Graphics g) {
          g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
       }        
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me and explain what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After pressing the binary button, the a new instance of ImagePanel is assigned to the variable `imagePanel`. However, this new ImagePanel is not added to the JFrame. The old ImagePanel remains added to the JPanel.

Comment: `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`  Why binary as opposed to `image.getType()`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what kind of image processing you're trying to do. The code..

```
image = new BufferedImage(
    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
```

..merely creates a new (blank) image with the byte binary type.  You haven't drawn anything into it.  That's why it's black.

To draw into it (for example to try to copy the original image), you can get a graphics context:

```
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
```

And then copy with something like:

```
g.drawImage(otherImage, 0, 0, this);
```

I'm not sure whether or how Java will do a conversion from a full depth RGB image to `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`.  You might get an exception.

Comment: I tried to convert the image into a binary image. Thanks alot! Just creating and not drawing into the image was the problem. Silly me!

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the image panel instead of the image. Also, you're not performing the actual painting on the binary image. Here is an example how to convert the original image to a binary, it is based on the provided code:

```
else if (e.getSource() == this.binaryButton) {
    BufferedImage mask = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics g = mask.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    g.dispose();
    image = mask;
    this.repaint();
}
```